# CSS attributes can not be applied via class on an img item

Tags: css

I am trying to apply some CSS styles via `class` attribute. Somehow this does not work.

It works directly via style attribute:

```
<img class="listImage lazy" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9; /* ie8 */" .. >
```

It does not work via class attribute:

```
.listImage.lazy{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

This one neither:

```
.listImage.lazy{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

How can I apply styles to the class listImage?

Comment: How about <img class="listImage"> and .listImage{...}?
If you want to assign your css to .listImage and .lazy then you need to define it like this: .listImage, .lazy {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply styles to the class listImage simply like this:

```
.listImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

If you wish to add the same style to both of your classes then you need to write it like this:

```
.listImage, .lazy {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Note that you assigned the class listImage and the class lazy to your img tag.

Comment: You are right. I was altering the wrong style file due to a similar name. Thank you for the help, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It works with no problem even if you use 2 classes.

```css
.listImage.lazy {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto\9;
}
```

```html
<img class="listImage lazy" src="https://i.imgur.com/d97bGiU.png"/>
```